# Is it possible for podcast audio stream to have script/text?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, podcast, webvtt, .lrc

Is it possible for podcast audio stream to have script/text?

I am interested in file formats for audio and timed text and how well these formats are supported by players (Android/iPhone/desktop).

I found:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebVTT

but have no idea how this or any other possible timed text format can be used in audio streaming.

My use case is creating language learning podcast and embed script into audio file.

Do I need to use [video container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) to provide text with audio?

Is it normal to provide links to MP4/AVI/MPEG containers in RSS/Atom feeds to podcast? Do podcast players understand containers formats?

Comment: a container gives you multiple channels (audio + other[video]) so that will work ... doubt this is possible otherwise